# GWT setCapture works in Firefox too, how?

Tags: javascript, firefox, gwt

I have a draggable element in my page. When user starts dragging and then releases mouse button **outside of Firefox** I need to receive mouseup so that I can stop dragging.

IE has setCapture for this but FF doesn't have. GWT has it too which works in FF too.

How does it works in FF? How can I do that in my JS code for FF?

(I like to know how it works, not just using xyz JS framework).

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source of a framework that does it?

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler - I will do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the answer is to add mousemove and mouseup event listener to document.

Thanks @Jeremy!